# Hockeyapp configuration with jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hockeyapp, jenkins-job-dsl

I am working on hybrid app and having two branch iOS and Android.
How do I configure a Jenkins build with hockeyapp?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install [HockeyApp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HockeyApp+Plugin) on jenkins

After installation, you will get  **Default HockeyApp Configuration** option in http://jenkins-server:port/configure

Default HockeyApp Configuration

```
Default API Token   <*provide the api token*> **you will get from hockey account
HTTP Client Timeout <leave empty>   
Enable global Debug Mode    <keep unchech>
```

on job configuration page there is **Add post-build action** option in which select **Upload to HockeyApp**

```
API Token   <Leave blank if you have done previous step >

Upload Method = Upload App / Upload Version (select as per your requirement)

App File = location of app file

Symbols (.dSYM.zip or mapping.txt) =  An optional path, relative to the build's workspace, to the generated dSYM.zip (iOS and MacOS) or mapping.txt (Android) file.

Packed libraries (.zip) = Optional path

Release Notes = No Release Notes/Use Change Log/Load Release Notes from File/Input Release Notes  (select as per your choice)

Allow Downloads      (select as per your choice)

Restrict Downloads to Tags  (you can restrict downloads of your app to only users/devices with these tags.)

Notify Team     (select as per your choice)
```

Delete old Versions (select as per your choice)

Comment: I did all these steps exactly and yet I get a 400 error. Can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760507/upload-to-hockeyapp-from-jenkins