# Upload to HockeyApp from Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hockeyapp

I have hosted and running builds in jenkins using AWS ubuntu machine. I want to upload the build once the build is generated in the post build process.

I added HockeyApp plugin in the jenkins and created an API token with full access after signing up in HockeyApp.

I entered the api token, mentioned Upload app and the file path.

I however get the below error and I am not sure where am I going wrong

```
Got unexpected response code from HockeyApp: 400
{"errors":{"credentials":["api token invalid"]}}
Build step 'Upload to HockeyApp' marked build as failure
```

I am generating the api token from the link https://appcenter.ms/settings/apitokens

Comment: the toke created in the hockey app has any expiration ? like 5 mins or something ?

Comment: No! I do not see any information that it expires neither it has an option to set when the expire should be

Comment: Its a free account I am using now

Comment: I am generating the api token with the link https://appcenter.ms/settings/apitokens

Comment: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-basics-and-authentication as per this link the hockey app will be transitioning into App Center on Nov. 16 , 2019.

Comment: So the plugin now is useless? It by default connects to `rink.hockeyapp.com`

Comment: Ah! Just found this https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55013

Answer (score 2):

You should go to [HockeyApp App token page](https://rink.hockeyapp.net/manage/auth_tokens) to create the API token, the link in your answer is from AppCenter, which is the next generation of HockeyApp. Now the two platforms have separate API tokens and you should use the corresponding token in each one.

HockeyApp and HockeyApp jenkins plugin are still working, and as yash said above, HockeyApp is going to close on Nov.16, refer thier declaration [here](https://hockeyapp.net/#s). I guess the plugin will retire at that time, but it's still working now.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue and i'm configuring everything on rink.hockeyapp.net. Something is up with the api/plugin i reckon.

Comment: I'm using the plugin without any problem, so I guess the issue still addresses in the token itself, you could go to HockeyApp support to raise a ticket there.

Comment: I transitioned to app-center plugin itself instead of HockeyApp plugin. It goes without any issues.